# Slack post message return "not_authed"

Tags: javascript, fetch, slack-api

I am trying to send message to channel of slack with the help of `chat.postMessage` slack api. Whenever I tried to send this request I get error saying 'not_authed'.

Kindly note I have disabled cors for this to use this api in my chrome for testing purpose.

```
  sendMessage() {

    console.log(this.messageForm.value);
    let d = this.messageForm.value;
    let token = "290485029384502934850293485=0-234850293485";
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        text: d.message,
        channel: d.channel,
      },
    };
    fetch("http://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage", options)
      .then((data) => {
        if (!data.ok) {
          throw Error();
        }
        return data.json();
      })
      .then((update) => {
        console.log(update);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Was the token intentionally masked here? The token that you would use for this method call would start with either `xoxp-` or `xoxb-`, which might be why you're seeing the `not_authed` error.  There's more information about tokens here: https://api.slack.com/authentication/token-types